# Auto generate Meta Description for imported products

Tags: magento-1.9, meta

i create a module for Auto generate of meta description but it's not workin for imported products but i want this also work for imported product & i am using an extension instead of magento's default import/Export
code is

```
app/etc/modules/Easylife_Meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Easylife_Meta>
<codePool>local</codePool>
<active>true</active>
<depends>
<Mage_Catalog />
</depends>
</Easylife_Meta>
</modules>
</config>

app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/etc/config.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Easylife_Meta>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</Easylife_Meta>
</modules>
<global>
<models>
<easylife_meta>
<class>Easylife_Meta_Model</class>
</easylife_meta>
</models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
<events>
<catalog_product_save_before><!-- observe the event -->
<observers>
<easylife_meta>
<class>easylife_meta/observer</class>
<method>autoMetaDescription</method>
</easylife_meta>
</observers>
</catalog_product_save_before>
</events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/Model/Observer.php

<?php 
class Easylife_Meta_Model_Observer {
public function autoMetaDescription($observer) {
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

$meta_description = $product->getMetaDescription();
$attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
$attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
$attributeSetName = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();

if($attributeSetName == "Books"){
$publisher_attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('publisher');
$metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at booksnclicks.com | Buy New Book | Authorised seller for ".$publisher_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
$product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
}



if($attributeSetName == "Gadgets"){
$metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at booksnclicks.com | Buy New Gadgets |Authorised seller for ". $product->getAttributeText('brand_gadgets');
$product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
}

if($attributeSetName == "Stationery"){
$metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at sbooksnclicks.com | Buy New Stationery | Authorised seller for ". $product->getAttributeText('brand_stationery');
$product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
}



} 
}
```

Comment: Import means from import from admin>import/export section?

Comment: i suggest use global tag instead of  adminhtml

Comment: @Amit Bera adminhtml use like this <adminhtml></adminhtml> but use global tag

Comment: yes.. please check